# override form name of masterpage vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, master-pages

It seems like I can't set the id or name of the form in my masterpage. [it's always "aspnetForm"]

Is there a way to override the uniqueID property of form?

I tried to create a class and inherit from htmlform, but then i can't register it on my mastrepage, [unknown server tag ... ]

im registering it like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cf" Namespace="Framework.BaseForm" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i implemented this and it's working

create a class called 'BaseForm' that inherits from HtmlForm

override the UniqueID property and return the name that you want.

register this in your masterpage using <%@ Register TagPrefix="cf" Namespace="Framework.BaseForm" %>

and replace the

```
<form></form> tags with <cf:BaseForm></cf:BaseForm>
```

my problem was that the masterpage couldn't find the code for BaseForm, i had to put it in app_code

Answer (score 2):

Found this, which should answer your questions...

> Unfortunately you can't change the ID
>   of an ASP.NET form.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1300826.aspx

and

http://forums.asp.net/p/883974/929349.aspx

Comment: you can change the id of the form in masterpage when you override the uniqueId property